# How can I tell if my program is being used through its COM interface?

Tags: delphi, com

I have a stand alone program written in Delphi to which I have added a COM interface. How can my program tell whether it was invoked through COM or from the command line?

In the unit that implements the interface there is this code:

```
initialization
  TAutoObjectFactory.Create(ComServer, TMyInterface, Class_MyInterface,
    ciSingleInstance, tmSingle);
```

I thought maybe the ComServer parameter here would be the main form ComServer property but I can't figure out how to use it or even if that is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inspect [ComServer.StartMode](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Win.ComServ.TComServer.StartMode):
[image]

Comment: The ComServer.StartMode can be read from within the unit that creates the interface.

Comment: _ComServer_ is a global variable declared in _System.Win.ComServ_.

Answer (score 0):

I also received this information from tech support. "Check the command line when the program starts." I did this and found the -Embedding switch.

Comment: This seems like it may not work for a server that can have multiple clients?